# How to access your data within a Python script in PowerBi

Tags: python, powerbi

This will probably be an easy question for many of you but as I am still very new to PowerBi and I can't find any solving answers on Google so I'm asking here:

The title is pretty much selfexplanatory. My question is, how do I access my data in PowerBi?
I've already connected PowerBi to my data-warehouse and simple visualization such as piecharts etc. work fine. I wanted to create a more complex visualization using Python but I'm unsure how to actually access the data-warehouse and use the tables in it in my script.

Answer (score 0):

You can run Python scripts in Power BI from the "Transform" tab under the Edit queries section. There is an option to select "Run Python Script". Once you select this option a dialog box will open and you can write the Python script you want. The following video highlights how you can access existing tables in the Python script:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pF_JZk_ghCM

Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks :)